Nuxt 3 app on Azure with Bitbucket Pipeline
I am a bit lost here in many tutorials that never really seem to help. I am trying to deploy a Nuxt 3 application to Azure Static Web Apps with Bitbucket.
The pipeline in Bitbucket looks like this:
pipelines:
    branches:
        main:
            - step:
                  name: Deploy to test
                  deployment: test
                  script:
                      # https://github.com/Azure/static-web-apps/issues/1325#issuecomment-1833538182
                      - chown -R 165536:165536 $BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR
                      - pipe: microsoft/azure-static-web-apps-deploy:main
                        variables:
                            APP_LOCATION: "$BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR/"
                            API_LOCATION: "$BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR/.output/server"
                            OUTPUT_LOCATION: "$BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR/.output/public"
                            API_TOKEN: $deployment_token

But once I push into the branch it just hangs at Running 'npm install'... and then (after like 58 minutes or so) fails with docker memory limit exceeded. The app isn't particulary big and a local build works fine. I added
nitro: {
        preset: "azure"
    },

to nuxtConfig and generated a staticwebapp.config.json using nuxi build but this all seems like grasping at straws since it wouldn't even start to build according to the Bitbucket pipeline log.
If it doesn't fail with the memory limit I get this message:

Has anyone got experience deploying Nuxt 3 to Azure with Bitbucket and can help me out here?
Thanks

If Possible, can you share your repository.

Why you are Using this command - chown -R 165536:165536 $BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR in your YAML.

Can you share your package.json file.

By using your YAML file, I successfully deployed a basic Nuxt 3 web app to Azure Static Web Apps without any issues.

I followed this document to deploy a Nuxt 3 app to Azure Static Web App using Bitbucket.
I created a simple Nuxt 3 app, deployed it to Azure Static Web App using Bitbucket, and the process was successful.
I added the following lines to my package.json file to specify the node version:
 "engines": {
    "node": ">=18.0.0"
  },

Below is my complete package.json.
package.json:
{
  "name": "nuxt-app",
  "private": true,
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview",
    "postinstall": "nuxt prepare"
  },
   "engines": {
    "node": ">=18.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "nuxt": "^3.11.2",
    "vue": "^3.4.21",
    "vue-router": "^4.3.0"
  }
}

nuxt.config.ts:
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  devtools: { enabled: true },
  nitro: {
    preset: "azure"
},
})

For deployment purposes, I ran the command below:
nuxi build

staticwebapp.config.json:
{
  "routes": [
    {
      "route": "/index.html",
      "redirect": "/"
    },
    {
      "route": "/",
      "rewrite": "/api/server"
    }
  ],
  "platform": {
    "apiRuntime": "node:18"
  },
  "navigationFallback": {
    "rewrite": "/api/server"
  }
}

I used your YML file and deployed it to the Azure Static Web App.
bitbucket-pipelines.yml:
pipelines:
    branches:
        main:
            - step:
                  name: Deploy to test
                  deployment: test
                  script:
                      - chown -R 165536:165536 $BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR
                      - pipe: microsoft/azure-static-web-apps-deploy:main
                        variables:
                            APP_LOCATION: "$BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR/"
                            API_LOCATION: "$BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR/.output/server"
                            OUTPUT_LOCATION: "$BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR/.output/public"
                            API_TOKEN: $deployment_token

The deployment was successful, as below.

Azure Static Web Output:

